# What is the preferred method of installing bootstrap for ng-bootstrap compatibility?

Tags: ng-bootstrap

1. The ng-bootstrap website states bootstrap.js may interefere with ng-bootstrap.
2. Installing bootstrap with "npm install boostrap" installs the folder "/node_modules/bootstrap/js".

Will this conflict with ng-bootstrap? If so, what's the best way to prevent this conflict?
Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Navigate to your project folder, open a new shell window and do

```
npm install --save @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
```

after that, you can add the following to your `module.ts`

```
import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@NgModule({
  ...
  imports: [NgbModule, ...],
  ...
})
export class YourAppModule {
}
```

Comment: That answers how to install ng-bootstrap, but that wasn't the question. The question is IF installing default bootstrap (which installs the javascript files) conflicts with ng-bootstrap's javascript, and if so how to rectify the issue.

Comment: it can conflict but does not have to. Nevertheless it's recommended to use ng-bootstrap.js.

Comment: @karottenbunker how do you use bootstrap components that require bootstrap.js? For example I also need navbar nav and the collapse and toggler component to enable mobile friendly menus in my app. These require bootstrap js as far as I can tell